# Cannot delete selected items in LIstView after using AlertDialog

Tags: android-studio, android-listview, android-alertdialog, contextmenu, multiple-choice

Here's my problem:

In my app, I have set ChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL) and the method of MultiChoiceModeListener for my ListView in order to allow user to delete items in the list by using context menu. I have put the following code in onActionItemClicked method and everything work fine:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        //Clear the list of selected item's id when the user exit the context menu bar.
        mSelectedItemIdList.clear();
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_select_delete:
                    deleteSelectedItem();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        private void deleteSelectedItem(){
    int totalRowDeleted = 0;

    if (!mSelectedItemIdList.isEmpty()){
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItemIdList.size(); i++){
            long idInDatabase = mSelectedItemIdList.get(i);
            Uri selectedItemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TimeEntry.CONTENT_URI, idInDatabase);
            int rowDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(selectedItemUri, null, null);

            if (rowDeleted != 0){
                totalRowDeleted++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (totalRowDeleted == 0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.delete_error_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, totalRowDeleted + " " + getString(R.string.delete_success_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But after I added the AlertDialog for confirmation like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_select_delete:
            showDeleteSelectedConfirmationDialog();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

private void showDeleteSelectedConfirmationDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_selected_confirmation));
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            deleteSelectedItem();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

The App doesn't crash but **deleteSelectedItem() doesn't work** anymore! Somehow the program **doesn't reach the things in the for loop inside the method**. Maybe there are some simple mistakes I have made. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The onDestroyActionMode() method is called everytime the AlertDialog show up. So, I have deleted the code in onDestroyActionMode() and add the code for clearing my list after the records are deleted.

```
private void deleteSelectedItem(){
int totalRowDeleted = 0;

if (!mSelectedItemIdList.isEmpty()){
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItemIdList.size(); i++){
        long idInDatabase = mSelectedItemIdList.get(i);
        Uri selectedItemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TimeEntry.CONTENT_URI, idInDatabase);
        int rowDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(selectedItemUri, null, null);

        if (rowDeleted != 0){
            totalRowDeleted++;
        }
    }
}

if (totalRowDeleted == 0){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.delete_error_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, totalRowDeleted + " " + getString(R.string.delete_success_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//Clear the list of selected item's id after delete the records.
mSelectedItemIdList.clear();
```

}